# Advice on how to include a function as condition in sumif

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to sum the values in a range only corresponding to the row of current month.
I am using the formula
=sumif(A6:A17 ,"=TEXT(TODAY(),'mmmm')", E6:M17)

A6 to A17 has the 12 months, so I want the sum of row 7 from the range E6:M17

But I am getting 0 as result. Please help.

The function I used as the second argument is no equating to the manual months name in A6:a17.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
=SUM(FILTER(E6:M17,A6:A17=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM")))
```

- 

[image]